# Is there a function to return which phrase in array the row matched when using LIKE ANY (array['%term1%', '%term2%', etc.])?

Tags: sql, postgresql, wildcard

I want all tables from my schema that match a list of other tables with similar names from a different schema. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) ColCount
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_2' and TABLE_NAME LIKE ANY (array[
'%table1%', 
'%table2%',
'%table3%',
'%table4%',
'%table5%'])
```

I want another column added to the output which specifies which name in the array the table from schema_2 matched, i.e.

```
TABLE_NAME COL_COUNT  SCHEMA_1_TABLE
table1a    15         table1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a join.  Kind of like:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT unnest(array['%table1%','%table2%','%table3%','%table4%','%table5%']) 
    AS table)
SELECT
    isc.TABLE_NAME,
    COUNT(isc.COLUMN_NAME),
    REPLACE(a.table,'%','')
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
    LEFT JOIN a ON (isc.TABLE_NAME LIKE a.table)
WHERE
    isc.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_2'
    AND a.table IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    isc.TABLE_NAME,
    a.table
```

You could also join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES in order to just detect any duplication, not just the ones specified.